# Laravel dusk is not able to type the complete input

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to make a test case on Laravel Dusk, where I'm typing out in the input field, I get to see some weird functionality sometimes it doesn't type the complete characters and process the next assertion/test.

I tried placing the pause but it is not helping me out.

```
$browser->assertPathIs($this->url())
    ->type('@stock-update-name', 'keshgjkfsdh289359846359462svfcvbjn8475645ksjdhgjfsg5')
    ->pause(1000)
    ->press('@stock-update-submit')//clicked on the button and redirected to table and show the expected filled content
    ->waitFor('.swal2-shown')
    ->assertSee('Oops!')
    ->assertSee('The given data was invalid')
    ->press('OK')
    ->assertSee('The name may not be greater than 20 characters.')
    ->type('@stock-update-name', '@#$786jdf')
    ->press('@stock-update-submit')//clicked on the button and redirected to table and show the expected filled content
    ->waitFor('.swal2-shown')
    ->assertSee('Oops!')
    ->assertSee('The given data was invalid')
    ->press('OK')
    ->assertSee('The name format is invalid.')
    ->type('@stock-update-name', 'instock')//check for valid stock name
    ->press('@stock-update-submit')
    ->waitFor('.swal2-shown')
    ->assertSee('stock has been updated.')
    ->press('OK')
    ->waitForLocation($this->url())
    ->pause(3000);
```

It should type the whole characters but sometimes it types 3 characters or 5 characters, most of my test cases are failing due to this.

Comment: Hi. How do you now how many characters were typed?
Did you check if you have any javascript manipulating the input value as Dusk is typing?

Comment: @xyz I've configured chrome window to detach, so that I can see in action whats going on, I saw that the characters were not typed and my tests failed due to this.

Comment: Okay. Did check if you have any javascript interferring with the field value? Validation scripts etc.